# problem in bathy objects conversion to raster

Tags: macos

I am trying to create a raster out of the bathy object using marmap package. The codes being -

load Hawaii bathymetric data
data(Hawaii)

use as.raster
r.hawaii <- as.raster(hawaii)

I get this result - 
Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "bathy"
But in the following, the code seems to work fine - 
https://rdrr.io/cran/marmap/man/as.raster.html

Comment: Please manage the formatting of your post for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of poor handling (masking) of generic functions in the marmap package. You can avoid the problem by first loading the raster package, and then the marmap package. (it is also confusing that it uses `as.raster` instead of `raster`; because the default `as.raster` is from grDevices and does not create a RasterLayer)

```
library(marmap)
#Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'adehabitatMA':
#  method                       from
#  print.SpatialPixelsDataFrame sp  
#  print.SpatialPixels          sp  
#Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#  method         from 
#  [.quosures     rlang
#  c.quosures     rlang
#  print.quosures rlang
# 
#Attaching package: ‘marmap’
#
#The following object is masked from ‘package:grDevices’:
#
#    as.raster

data(hawaii)
r <- as.raster(hawaii)
```

Now load the raster package and it fails

```
library(raster)
#Loading required package: sp
r <- as.raster(hawaii)
#Error in UseMethod("as.raster") : 
#  no applicable method for 'as.raster' applied to an object of class "bathy"
```

Things work if instead you do

```
library(raster)
library(marmap)
data(hawaii)
r <- as.raster(hawaii)
```

Comment: Or since you are warned that `as.raster` is `masked from package:grDevices` when loading marmap, you could just be more specific by calling `marmap::as.raster(hawaii)`